# Generating the keys for the RSA cryptosystem in probabilistic polynomial time

Tags: rsa, public-key, key-generation

In general every public key cryptosystem ``has'' a probabilistic polynomial time algorithm $G$ such that $G(1^k)=(\textrm{public key}, \textrm{private key=trapdoor})$; $G$ is called the key generator. Now for the RSA cryptosystem the keys, can be found in the following way:

> Bob decides the key length $k$, then $G(1^k)=((n,e), d)$ where $n=pq$
>   with $p$ and $q$  prime numbers, $n$ has length $k$ (as bit string),  and $e\in\mathbb
>  Z^\ast_{\phi(n)}$. The two primes $p$ and $q$  and are chosen in a
>   random way, $\phi(n)$ is simply $(p-1)(q-1)$, $e\in\mathbb
> Z^\ast_{\phi(n)}$ is randomly chosen and finally $d$ is calculated  in
>   polynomial time with the extended Euclid algorithm. The couple $(n,e)$
>   is setted as  the public key, whereas $d$ is the secret key.

I don't understand why this algorithm has probabilistic polynomial running time. Who ensures that I can find two random primes and $e$ in a reasonable time?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically, there are a lot of primes available to choose from.

Comment: Yes this is the intuition, but is there a formal proof aof this?

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371291 $\;$

Answer (score 1):

Short version: All the cool kids are using Randomized Algorithm !

Boring version:

1. Any deterministic (part of a) crypto system can be broken !  [Goldwasser Micali]
2. Primes density is pretty high (higher than one intuitively expects) as we talk of big numbers. Prime No. Theorem : #of primes between $1$ and $x$, $\pi(x) = \frac{x}{ln(x)}$ , So if randomly picking no.s usually means you have a fairly high chance of getting a prime.. :)
3. Primality checking with Rabin Miller (probabilistic) is way faster than AKS (deterministic)

Comment: "=" $\mapsto$ "$\approx$" $\;$

Comment: yes, i could not find the latex code for that :P